# Error in Angular with shared Module: generates "appears in XXX.module but itself has errors"

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, module, shared

Ionic v6 project with Angular. I have made several directives that I need to use in several pages. I have created a shared module:

```
import { MediaPage } from './../directivas/media/media.page';
import { TformPage } from './../directivas/tform/tform.page';
import { ViewformPage } from './../directivas/viewform/viewform.page';
import { TristatePage } from './../directivas/tristate/tristate.page';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { BtitleDirective } from './../directivas/btitle.directive';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
          BtitleDirective,
          TristatePage,
          ViewformPage,
          TformPage,
          MediaPage
      ],
      imports: [
      ],
      exports:[
          CommonModule,
          IonicModule,
    
          BtitleDirective,
          TristatePage,
          ViewformPage,
          TformPage,
          MediaPage
      ]
    
    })
    export class SharedModule { }
```

I have the following error on each module that uses SharedModule:

```
SharedModule Appears in the NgModule.imports of HomePageModule, but itself has errors
```

These errors appear in VSCode and with ionic build, but with ionic serve everything is working well,

Any ideas?

Comment: This error just states something is wrong with your SharedModule. If you could create a stackblitz I will take a look.

Comment: Thanks! I work with gitlab, so I can't connect from stackblitz. I have explained the problem in my following answer

Answer (score 0):

I have found a part of the problem. I have a component directive called TriState, showing 3 buttons. This is tristate.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { TristatePageRoutingModule } from './tristate-routing.module';

import { TristatePage } from './tristate.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    TristatePageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [TristatePage],
})
export class TristatePageModule {}
```

tristate.page.ts

```
import { UtilService } from './../../services/util.service';
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, forwardRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tristate',
  templateUrl: './tristate.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tristate.page.scss'],
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => TristatePage),
    multi: true
}]

})
export class TristatePage implements ControlValueAccessor,OnInit {
  @Input() label: string = '';
  @Input() readonly: boolean;

  @Output() onchange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  value: string ;

  onChange: (_: any) => void = (_: any) => {}; //Invoked when the model has been changed
  onTouched: () => void = () => {}; // Invoked when the model has been touched

  constructor(
      public utilS: UtilService
  ) {}
  public ngOnInit(){
    console.log('oninit tri',this.value);
    this.value='';
  }

  public setvalue() {
     //console.log($event,this.value);
    if(this.readonly) return;
    //this.value = this.options[p].value;
    this.updateChanges();
    if(this.onchange)
        this.onchange.emit(this.value);
  }

  /**
   * Method that is invoked on an update of a model.
   */
  updateChanges() {
    if(!this.value) return;
    console.log('updchange',this.value);
    this.onChange(this.value);
  }


  ///////////////
  // OVERRIDES //
  ///////////////

  /**
   * Writes a new item to the element.
   * @param value the value
   */
  writeValue(value: string): void {
    console.log('write ',this.value);
    if(value) 
        this.value = value;
    this.updateChanges();
  }

  /**
   * Registers a callback function that should be called when the control's value changes in the UI.
   * @param fn
   */
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  /**
   * Registers a callback function that should be called when the control receives a blur event.
   * @param fn
   */
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
}
```

And tristate.page.html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
        <h3>{{label}}</h3>
        <ion-segment (click)="setvalue()" [(ngModel)]="value" >
            <ion-segment-button value="S" style="--background-checked:green;" >
                Sí
              <ion-icon name="{{utilS.conficons.S}}"></ion-icon>
            </ion-segment-button>

            <ion-segment-button value="P" style="--background-checked:orange">
              <ion-icon name="{{utilS.conficons.P}}"></ion-icon>
              N/C
            </ion-segment-button>
            
            <ion-segment-button value="N" style="--background-checked:red;">
                No
                <ion-icon name="{{utilS.conficons.N}}"></ion-icon>
           </ion-segment-button>
 
          </ion-segment>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I remove TristatePage from module declarations, above errors "SharedModule Appears in the NgModule.imports of...", disappear, but I have a new one in template:

```
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-segment'.
```

I don't understand what happens..:(

Answer (score 0):

It's as the error says: ngModel isn't a known property of ion-segment.
[link to ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/segment)

The only way I can see to get the selected segment is to use the 'ionChange' event as documented in the ionic docs.

In your html:

```
<ion-segment (ionChange)="segmentChanged($event)">
```

In your typescript:

```
segmentChanged(ev: any) {
   console.log('Segment changed', ev);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! I have removed ngModel and added ionChange. I had same problem in another component using ion-input. Running with ion serve worked perfect, but I couldn't build the application!.   ionic docs shows an example using ion-input with ngModel!!